# jQuery javascript - scrollTop animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = "index";
    var park = "park";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            url="http://openAPI.seoul.go.kr:8088/4150495f32313037XXXXX/json/SearchParkInfoService/1/20"
            $.getJSON(url,function(result) {
                var jsonObject = result.SearchParkInfoService;
                var totalCount = jsonObject.list_total_count;
                var row = jsonObject.row;
                document.write("<span id='topOfArticle'><b>원하는 공원을 목록에서 찾아보세요~</b></span>");
                document.write("<form> <select name = 'parkList'>");
                for (var i = 0 ; i < row.length ; i++) {
                    document.write("<option value = '" + row[i].P_IDX + "'>" + row[i].P_PARK + "</option>");
                }
                document.write("</select><input type='button' value='보러가기' onClick='checkIt(this.form)'>");
                for (var i = 0 ; i < row.length ; i++) {
                    document.write("<p id=" + row[i].P_IDX + "><h3><b>" + (i+1) + ". " + row[i].P_PARK + " (공원번호 " + row[i].P_IDX + ")</b></h3></p>");
                    document.write("<p><img src='" + row[i].P_IMG + "' width=150px border=1dp></p>");
                    document.write("<b>공원 설명 : </b><blockquote>" + row[i].P_LIST_CONTENT + "</blockquote>");
                    document.write("<p><b>위치(GRS80TM) : </b>경도 " + row[i].G_LONGITUDE + " / 위도 " + row[i].G_LATITUDE + "</p>");
                    document.write("<p><b>위치(WGS84) : </b>경도 " + row[i].LONGITUDE + " / 위도 " + row[i].LATITUDE + "</p>");
                    document.write("<p><b>주소 : </b>" + row[i].P_ADDR + "</p>");
                    document.write("<p><a href=http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+row[i].LATITUDE+","+row[i].LONGITUDE+"&zoom=14&size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C"+row[i].LATITUDE+","+row[i].LONGITUDE+"&sensor=true target=_blank> 지도에서 찾아보기(Google Maps) </a></p>");
                    document.write("<p><b>지역 및 관리부서 : </b>" + row[i].P_ZONE + " " + row[i].P_DIVISION + "</p>");
                    document.write("<p><b>전화번호 : </b>" + row[i].P_ADMINTEL + "</p>");
                    document.write("<font align='right'><a href='#top'> Top으로 가기 </a></font>");
                    document.write("<hr color=#cd67ff>");
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function checkIt(form) {
        var targetOffset = $(form.parkList.selectedIndex+1).offset().top;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:targetOffset}, 'fast');
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>서울시 공원 정보를 조회하세요!</h2>
    <button>정보보러 가긔~</button>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to click the button, "보러가기", an option value button, then scroll to selectedIndex list in same window.

in `function checkIt(from)`,

there is an error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.
```

I do not know how can i fix it.

Comment: Try this link. It may help :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866629/jquery-scrolltop-if-url-has-hash

Comment: I doubt `$(form.parkList.selectedIndex+1)` is a good selector. It looks wrong to me

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that `$(form.parkList.selectedIndex+1)` is undefined i.e. it's null. Try and put a break point in and see if the selector is returning anything. 
Also I think you can use `offsetTop()` as opposed to `offset().top`, but I'm not 100% on this.

You may also want to try something like `$('#'+form.parkList.selectedIndex+1)` if you are trying to select by id or `$('.'+form.parkList.selectedIndex+1)` if by class. It may also be that you want something like:

```
var index = form.parklist.selectedIndex+1;
$('#list').eq(index) ...
```

etc if you are trying to select the nth element in the list.

Comment: `(form.parkList.selectedIndex+1)` is correct value. and i cant solve it using `offsetTop()`. it is so difficult error for me. ;(